# Magento: programmatic search depending on store

Tags: php, search, magento

I'm using the catalogsearch module of Magento. I have 2 stores. When searching "test" on the first one, I get 5 results. When searching "test" on the second one, I get 3 results.

I'd like to add the results of the second store (just the number of results) when I search in the first one.

I added a block and a template, all I need is the code to retrieve the number of the results in the second store, and that's where I'm stucked.

I tried to get the controller code, but it always returns me the number of results in the first store :

> private function
>   _getStoreQuery($storeId)      {
>
> ```
>           $query = Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->getQuery();
>     $query->setStoreId(7);
>
>
>
>           if ($query->getQueryText()) {
>         if (Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->isMinQueryLength())
> ```
>
> {
>                   $query->setId(0)
>                       ->setIsActive(1)
>                       ->setIsProcessed(1);
>               }
>               else {
>                   if ($query->getId()) {
>                       $query->setPopularity($query->getPopularity()+1);
>                   }
>                   else {
>                       $query->setPopularity(1);
>                   }
>
> ```
>             $query->prepare();
>         }
>
>         Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->checkNotes();
>
>         if (!Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->isMinQueryLength())
> ```
>
> {
>                   $query->save();
>               }
>           }
>
> ```
>     var_dump($query);
>     return $query;
>
>       }
> ```

I also tried to change the store context before, but no luck:
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($secondStoreId);

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably the reason the first set of results is returned on your second try is because you are reusing the `Mage_Catalogsearch_Model_Query` object. You need to create a new set of results instead. Here the collection will create those, you just need to iterate through `$collection` to get them.

```
$queryText = Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->getQueryText();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/query_collection')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setQueryFilter($queryText);
```

Comment: I think it is indeed the problem, but your tip does not resolve it.

Comment: Here is the content of the collection: http://pastebin.com/BwiFEQbi
And when I try to iterate over it, it crashes Magento (page stops loading):
foreach ($collection as $col) { var_dump($col); }

The database contains also only one query (the one on store 1)

Comment: When I try the same thing I get this http://pastebin.com/nVKQPSky. If I search for something that doesn't exist the collection is empty and nothing crashes. In short, I cannot recreate what you are seeing.

Comment: Now I think about it, if it crashes when doing a dump it must be returning too much data on each object. I would use `var_dump($col->debug())` or `echo $col->getNumResults()`