# What's the proper way to call CatalogSearch from a custom Block in Magento?

Tags: magento, search

I'm writing a controller intended to expose Magento's catalog search functionality to API calls. Using filters with the default REST api just doesn't return the same quality results as the search feature available on a Magento site.

I've been digging for a few days now, and the various approaches I've seen here on Stack Overflow and Magento discussion boards don't seem to be working, is there a step I'm missing?

Both of these approaches return null, and I can't seem to figure out why:

```
 $query = Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->getQuery();

 $searcher = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->addFilters(
             array('name'=> $query->getQueryText(), 
             'description' => $query->getQueryText()));



 $obj = new stdClass();
 $obj->query = $query->getQueryText();
 $obj->results = $searcher->getProductCollection(); //nothing returned
```

Nor does the approach modified from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880473/magento-programmatic-search-depending-on-store) seem to work:

```
 $query = Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->getQuery();

 $obj = new stdClass();
 $obj->query = $query->getQueryText();

 if ($query->getQueryText()) {
      if (Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->isMinQueryLength()) {
           $query->setId(0)->setIsActive(1)->setIsProcessed(1);
      } else { 
           if ($query->getId()) { 
                $query->setPopularity($query->getPopularity()+1);
           } else { 
                $query->setPopularity(1);   
           }
           $query->prepare();
       }
       $obj->results = $query->getProductCollection(); //null
}
```

What steps am I missing to successfully call into Magento's catalog search module and get a collection of results back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento's search model is a bit more complex as they built a mechanism to save queries and results for caching and statistics. So, you need to prepare the query object, then prepare the result and then you can join the product collection with the search result table. Here is how to do it in code:

```
$searchText = 'ipad';
$query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText($searchText)->prepare();
$fulltextResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext')->prepareResult(
        Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/fulltext'), 
        $searchText, 
        $query
        );

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->getSelect()->joinInner(
            array('search_result' => $collection->getTable('catalogsearch/result')),
            $collection->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                'search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id=?',
                $query->getId()
            ),
            array('relevance' => 'relevance')
        );
```

$collection is a filtered down catalog product collection of which you can then perform any additional operations depending on what you need:

```
$collection->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());
$collection->addMinimalPrice();
$collection->addFinalPrice();
$collection->addTaxPercents();
$collection->addStoreFilter();
$collection->addUrlRewrite();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was incredibly helpful! There's just this last nagging bit: $obj->collection = $collection is returned as {} despite having a number of matches, how do I get the array of products out of $collection so the caller has some data it can use?

Comment: Try looping through the collection with a foreach statement and build your array. Should not be difficult once you have all your products in collection object. Although if your end goal is different from presenting products you may want to consider joining this collection to whatever you need in order to save on resources.

Comment: Shoot, I was hoping to avoid building a second collection through iteration. Thanks a million, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Any ideas why this code works from a Controller but not from a REST API endpoint? Apparently there's nothing to iterate over after calling ->getSelect()->joinInner from V1.php.

Comment: Not sure. Have you tried logging the actual sql query that is used in the collection at that point? Try loggin `(string)$collection->getSelect()` to see what is happening there.

Comment: Interesting, $collection->getSelect() returns null from V1.php but returns a query string in the controller action.

Comment: Does not work - getting SQL exception - see http://pastebin.com/yceAYW3P (Magento 1.6.2).

Comment: @BrMcMullin Have you found the solution for this "Any ideas why this code works from a Controller but not from a REST API endpoint" ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @DDR I'm afraid not - this ended up blocking the project completely. Sorry!

Comment: Sir, I have similar problem. I want to create a module to display result using four category..<br/> like cartridge -> toner -> Brand -> Model. can you please suggest me how to use this code. rightnow when click search button its redirect to http://hostname/catalogsearch/advanced/swresult/?category=21&subcategory=31&subsubcategory=73&subtype=2677

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$searchQuery = "your search query";
$storeId = "your store id";
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel("catalog/product_collection")->addAttributeToSelect("*");
$query = Mage::helper("catalogSearch")->getQuery();
$query->setStoreId($storeId);
$query->setQueryText($searchQuery);
$collection = $query->getSearchCollection();
$collection->addSearchFilter($searchQuery);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect("*");
$collection->addAttributeToFilter("status", 1);
foreach($collection as $_product) {
    //do your iteration
}
```

or in Ron's answer just set store in environment before executing code and unset it after the code like this.

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton("core/app_emulation");
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

//Ron's Code

$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```